# Erwachsenenlakritz - Kein Kinderlakritz

Tags: difference

I bought this can of liquorice. At the back, it lists the ingredients in four languages. But for German, there is an additional row of text below the ingredients which says "ERWACHSENENLAKRITZ - KEIN KINDERLAKRITZ", which means "adult liquorice - not child liquorice".

What's the difference between adult liquorice and child liquorice? As far as I know, there's no similar partitioning in English nor Swedish (my mother tongue).

Is adult liquorice perhaps salt liquorice (salmiak)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [Wikipedia - Lakritze](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakritze)

> Ein weiterer charakteristischer Bestandteil von Lakritzwaren ist Ammoniumchlorid, auch Salmiak genannt. In Deutschland dürfen Lebensmittel ohne Warnhinweis auf der Verpackung nicht mehr als 2 Prozent Salmiak enthalten. Lakritzwaren mit einem höheren Gehalt an Salmiak müssen einen Warnhinweis auf der Verpackung haben. Dieser lautet:
>
> Erwachsenenlakritz – kein Kinderlakritz bei Gehalten über 2 % bis 4,49
>   %
>
> Extra stark, Erwachsenenlakritz  kein Kinderlakritz bei Gehalten über 4,49  bis 7,99 %

Comment: I'm not that good at German. Does it mean that the liquorice salmiak percentage is between 4.49 and 7.99?

Comment: Yeah, basically it means if the salmiak percentage is lower than 2% it's `Kinderlakritz`, between 2% and 4,49% it's called `Erwachsenenlakritz` and between 4,5% and 7,99% it is `Extra stark`.

Comment: @user5833 Actually it means that given the warning you read the salmiak percentage is between 2% and 4,49%.